# Thunderbird: "do not distract me" for one account

Tags: thunderbird

I have two email accounts at work: My personal account, which works the way I want it to by default, and a shared support account that gets messages every minute or so.

I am actually not in support, and the only time I need to be aware of activity there is when I am doing tests that involve creating many users on our site with unique email addresses and having them run a bunch of scripted actions. In this situation, I will check to make sure that notification emails were sent after the tests are complete. The reason that I use the support account for this is because our mail server is set up to redirect test-user-123@support.domain to support@domain with "test-user-123" in the subject line, where we then use our own personal filters to sort the messages in Thunderbird.

Is there any way that I can prevent one account from creating any sort of distractions, since I will know when I need to check that account? No popups, no "new mail" icon in the system tray, no blue text in the sidebar, nothing. I don't even want it to fetch messages automatically.

I've tried unchecking "Check for new messages at startup / every x minutes", but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This strange workflow isn't supported in Thunderbird. Use a different client or use an email server / provider that allows email suffixes like `your.email+some.suffix@gmail.com` and don't abuse the support account for testing; it gets enough abuse already.